# DBI: bind_param casts string to ntext -> nvarchar(max) and ntext are incompatible

Tags: sql, perl, dbi, ntext

I have a problem concerning perl DBI's bind_param. The following SQL works:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 'string'");
$sth->execute();
```

While the following doesn't:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$sth->execute('string');
```

The error the last query causes is:

```
[ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types nvarchar(max) and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. (SQL-42000)
```

It seems like `bind_param`, which gets called by `execute`, casts 'string' to ntext. How can I work around that?

Comment: Assuming you are using DBD::ODBC (which it looks like) then SQLBindParameter is called with a C type of SQL_C_CHAR and a parameter type of whatever the driver said the parameter was in SQLDescribeParam. If you have an up to date DBI and DBD::ODBC you can set DBI_TRACE=DBD=x.log and run your code and you'll see what it gets and does in x.log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider binding the value type prior the SQL call:

```
use DBI qw(:sql_types);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = ?" );

my $key = 'string';
my $sth->bind_param( 1, $key, SQL_VARCHAR );

$sth->execute();
```